# Display .hdr Uint8Array image in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hdr

In IndexedDB we have hdr images in the format of a Uint8Array. I retrieve these but need to display them in an image tag.

I have tried converting to base64 and setting image src to this with no luck.

```
`data:image/hdr;base64,${imageData}`
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the browser does not recognize the MIME type `image/hdr`. Your src prefix should be `data:image/png;base64,${imageData}`, see this post: [How to display Base64 images in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)